Remapping to numpad function keys not possible? (Mac)
I'm trying to remap the zoom-button from the command key to one of the available function keys on the numpad (for example f16, f17), in combination with the mouse/trackpad. I can configure the keymap in Blender (screenshot) but it still doesn't work. The default assigned key will stop working (as expected), but the new key won't respond. I'm a bit puzzled that Blender would recognise and register the new key, but then not respond to it when working on a file.
Am I doing something wrong?
Apologies if I've overlooked the obvious! - I'm pretty new to blender (version 3.4).

Cheers!
